# Jenkins integration for JIRA

Tags: jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin

I am looking for a documentation around Integrating JIRA with Jenkins. All I am trying to do is display the Jenkins build status in a dashboard in JIRA. I have installed *Jenkins Plugin for JIRA* and *JIRA Plugin for Jenkins* and went through the Atlassian marvelution [documentation](https://marvelution.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JJI/Features) but it is not clear how to configure the Jobs.

It will be nice if I could get some instructions around integrating the Jobs to JIRA and how to configure the jobs to show up in JIRA dashboard/ Activity page for a JIRA Issue

Answer (score 3):

The first step is try to configure JIRA and JENKINS server each working individually.

And then install the following Plugins in JENKINS and JIRA Separately

1) Jira Issue Updater:- This plugin can update Jira issues by changing their workflow status and adding comments. 1.11

2) JIRA plugin:- This plugin integrates Jenkins to Atlassian JIRA. 1.39

3) JIRA Plugin for Jenkins:- This plugin implements the Application Link API to support integration with Atlassian JIRA 1.5.3

4) JiraTestResultReporter plugin:- This plugin creates issues in Jira for failed unit tests.

Following add-on in JIRA server:-

1) JIRA Plugin to integrate Jenkins CI Version: 1.5.3 Vendor: Marvelution Add-on key: com.marvelution.jira.plugins.jenkins

2) JIRA Plugin to integrate Hudson CI Version: 5.0.4 Vendor: Marvelution Add-on key: com.marvelution.jira.plugins.hudson

After  installing the above plugins in Jenkins go to Global configuration under Manage Jenkins and add JIRA site name.

Similarly go to JIRA Administration, Hudson/Jenkins, Servers, Add Server, configure there your Jenkins server.

Comment: Which JIRA plugin we need to install in Jenkins? There is a JIRA plugin by the Jenkins community and there is one by Atlassian Marvelution.

Comment: Install the one by Jenkins community.But it's preferable to have  Atlassian Marvelution also as  it implements Application Link API.